# MS ACCESS webbrowser control file preview not working properly

Tags: ms-access, webbrowser-control, tiff

I've been trying to display files in a form using the webbrowser control and have had some success when displaying pdf's, however, if I want to display a TIFF file it wants to download the picture rather than displaying it.

I suppose the question I am asking is if the webbrowser control can display TIFF files. Is there a workaround?

Cheers

Eych

Answer (score 0):

You may need a more advanced *picture control* like [csXImage](https://www.chestysoft.com/ximage/default.asp) to display TIFF pictures.

The file, you can download with my *DownloadFile* function found in my article here:

[Show pictures directly from URLs in Access forms and reports](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/29679/Show-pictures-directly-from-URLs-in-Access-forms-and-reports.html)

and also on **GitHub**: [VBA.PictureUrl](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.PictureUrl.git)

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

' API declarations.
'
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "Urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
    ByVal pCaller As Long, _
    ByVal szURL As String, _
    ByVal szFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
    ByVal lpfnCB As Long) _
    As Long

' Download a file or a page with public access from the web. 
' Returns 0 if success, error code if not. 
' 
' If parameter NoOverwrite is True, no download will be attempted 
' if an existing local file exists, thus this will not be overwritten. 
' 
' Examples: 
' 
' Download a file: 
'   Url = "https://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/ProfileImages/%7Ba82bcf77-ba9f-4ec3-bbb3-1d9ce15cae23%7D.jpg" 
'   FileName = "C:\Test\CodeProjectProfile.jpg" 
'   Result = DownloadFile(Url, FileName) 
' 
' Download a page: 
'   Url = "https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1022704/Rounding-Values-Up-Down-By-Or-To-Significant-Figur?display=Print" 
'   FileName = "C:\Test\CodeProject1022704.html" 
'   Result = DownloadFile(Url, FileName) 
' 
' Error codes: 
' -2146697210   "file not found". 
' -2146697211   "domain not found". 
' -1            "local file could not be created." 
' 
' 2004-12-17. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH. 
' 2017-05-25. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH. Added check for local file. 
' 2017-06-05. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH. Added option to no overwrite the local file. 
' 
Public Function DownloadFile( _ 
    ByVal Url As String, _ 
    ByVal LocalFileName As String, _ 
    Optional ByVal NoOverwrite As Boolean) _ 
    As Long 

    Const BindFDefault  As Long = 0 
    Const ErrorNone     As Long = 0 
    Const ErrorNotFound As Long = -1

    Dim Result  As Long

    If NoOverwrite = True Then 
        ' Page or file should not be overwritten. 
        ' Check that the local file exists. 
        If Dir(LocalFileName, vbNormal) <> "" Then 
            ' File exists. Don't proceed. 
            Exit Function 
        End If 
    End If     

    ' Download file or page. 
    ' Return success or error code. 
    Result = URLDownloadToFile(0, Url & vbNullChar, LocalFileName & vbNullChar, BindFDefault, 0)   

    If Result = ErrorNone Then 
        ' Page or file was retrieved. 
        ' Check that the local file exists. 
        If Dir(LocalFileName, vbNormal) = "" Then 
            Result = ErrorNotFound 
        End If 
    End If   

    DownloadFile = Result 

End Function
```